# Scorecards in Google Sheets

Tags: charts, google-sheets

I want to add scorecards charts in Google Sheets.

I have found that this is possible: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9245873?hl=en

However, when I go to chart type I cannot find "Scorecard" under "Other"

Do I have to configure something else before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scorecard charts are part of the latest Google Sheets' update which is being rolled out at this moment. the update process may take 15-30 days to roll out for all platforms starting with G Suit accounts and ending with regular Google accounts. Eg. the recommended course of action is to wait in this case.

> [image: 0]